# .NET Regex - Help with regex 'alternatives' (Pipe symbol | )

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regex expression that I'm trying to construct that processes a file path and tries to find a file path whose directory ends with "Processed" or "Failed".

I have something like this...

```
        static string PROCESSED_DIRECTORY = "Processed";
        static string FAILURE_DIRECTORY = "Failed";

...
    if (Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"(.*)\\({0})|({1})$", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)))....
```

This works fine.

However, I created an additional Regex expression because I am also trying to match the occurance of a file that is located in the Processed or Failed directory.  The regex is not matching and I believe it has something to do with the pipe symbol.  It matches when I check for either 'Failed' or 'Processed' without the pipe symbol.

For example:  The following files don't match 
- C:\ftp\business\Processed\file.txt
- C:\ftp|business\Failed\file.txt

I would expect them to match.

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"(.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*)", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)))
```

If I somehow could combine the two Regex queries into one to say "Match a path that ends with Failed' or 'Processed' and also match a file that exists in the 'Failed' or 'Processed' directory", that'd be amazing.  Right now though, I'm content with having two separate regex calls and getting the second to work.

Comment: You say it fails, can you elaborate on that?  Do you get an exception, does it fail to match?  What test data are you using?

Comment: I adjusted to add more information

Comment: Works ok for me... Ran this in LINQPad:

string PROCESSED_DIRECTORY = "Processed";
string FAILURE_DIRECTORY = "Failed";

string FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp\business\Processed\file.txt";
Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"(.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*)", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)).Dump();

FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp|business\Failed\file.txt";
Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"(.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*)", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)).Dump();

Returned True for both.  Sorry comment field is eating my formatting...

Comment: @Pete, if I run that expression in .NET 4, I get an error saying too many parenthesis.  Did you purposely exclude the double slash '\\' from my original regex expression?

Comment: Nope, it was a funny paste.  I'll throw something up as an answer for formatting purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works ok for me... Ran this in LINQPad:

```
string PROCESSED_DIRECTORY = "Processed";
string FAILURE_DIRECTORY = "Failed";

string FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp\business\Processed\moof\file.txt";
Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"(.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*)", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)).Dump();


FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp|business\Failed\file.txt";
Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"(.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*)", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)).Dump();
```

Here's a version that will look for either containing the processed/failed strings OR ending in \Processed|Failed\filename.ext:

```
string PROCESSED_DIRECTORY = "ProcessedPath";
string FAILURE_DIRECTORY = "FailedPath";

string FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp\business\ProcessedPath\moof\file.txt";
Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"((.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*))|(.*\\(Processed|Failed)\\(?!.*\\.*))", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)).Dump();

FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp\business\NotTheProcessedPath\moof\Processed\file.txt";
Regex.IsMatch(FileFullPath, String.Format(@"((.*)\\({0}|{1})\\(.*))|(.*\\(Processed|Failed)\\(?!.*\\.*))", PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY)).Dump();
```

Comment: Wow, well this is my error.  The test data that I WAS USING (not what was posted in my question) was "C:\temp\Directory\Failed.txt" which wasn't matching...which it shouldn't.  Thanks :) :P

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to do this (progressively more complicated and more correct), but the simplest is probably this:

```
var targetStrings = new[] { PROCESSED_DIRECTORY, FAILURE_DIRECTORY }; //needles
string FileFullPath = @"C:\ftp\business\Processed\moof\file.txt"; //haystack

if (FileFullPath.Split('\\').Any(str => targetStrings.Contains(str)))
{
    //...
```

No regex required. Regex seems overkill and possibly error-prone for this anyway.

[System.IO.Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) may be relevant to whatever you're doing here; it's what the Path class was made for.